# Python error: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Pen'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to use the `Pen` functionality of `turtle` module in `Python` programming, but it gave me this error:

```
    [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
    >>> import turtle
    >>> t = turtle.Pen()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
        t = turtle.Pen()
    AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Pen'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no capital in pen...

it's:

```
import turtle
turtle.pen()
```

try doing `dir(turtle)` to see a list of functions available, in there you will see pen

[image: my shell]

Comment: I tried to do turtle.pen(), but it again gave me :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    turtle.pen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'pen'

Comment: restart your shell and make sure you aren't defining turtle as something else

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Confusingly, there are both `Pen` and `pen` functions in Python turtle.  One is a synonym for `Turtle`, the other returns or sets the pen attributes of a turtle.  You failed to do `turtle.Pen()` in your session above to prove your point, otherwise you would have seen it.  Often, beginners name one of their own source files `turtle.py` causing a failure to load Python's turtle.py

Comment: When I do `dir(turtle)`, `Pen` is the *second* item (right after `Canvas`) in the returned list of 171 symbols  so what point are you trying to make with respect to `dir` and `Pen`?  (The `pen` function is the 112th item returned, btw.)

Comment: Please see my answer below: you had installed the incorrect python package :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
```

Command line session:

```
% python3
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Pen()
>>> exit()
%
```

Make sure you don't have a file of your own lying around named `turtle.py` as this will interfere with loading Python's own `turtle.py` library:

```
% touch turtle.py
% python3
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Pen()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Pen'
>>>
```

Which generates the same "`AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Pen'`" you received.

Comment: Unexplained downvote?  I thought this was the newer, kinder SO.

Comment: XD feels like that sometimes...but not others

Answer (score 0):

Actual solution: you installed the incorrect package. You should have installed [PythonTurtle](https://pypi.org/project/PythonTurtle/)